# Quota in HTTP response

Tags: google-bigquery, quota

The adwords API returns the quota consumed by each request ( ie in the HTTP response to each request ). Can we have this feature replicated in the BigQuery API please?

Comment: Feature requests should be sent to https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/. Stack Overflow isn't the right place for them.

Answer (score 0):

Since the agency pays a lot to get that data out to BigQuery, better they request on Enterprise support https://enterprise.google.com/supportcenter/

or on the public issue tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/